# Matlab XTickLabels warning

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a simple plot in Matlab 2014b. For example's sake:

```
b1 = bar(1:12, rand(12,1));
ax1 = gca;
```

The following warning message pops up when using the XTickLabels property:

```
xticklabels = ax1.XTickLabels;
Warning: The XTickLabels property will be removed in a future release.
```

What is the preferred property to use instead at this point?

Comment: It appears that you've answered this yourself, but you should improve your question by providing a code example that replicates this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct property to use is `XTickLabel` not `XTickLabels`.